# mysql regex to match string with and without dots

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm trying to write a mysql query that will match names from a table and the name in the database can contain dots or no dots. So, for example I would like my query string "fast" to match all of these: "fast", "f.ast", "f.a.s.t" etc

I can't predict where the dots are going to be so using LIKE doesn't seem appropriate

```
SELECT * FROM teams WHERE (name LIKE "%fast%" OR `name` LIKE "%f.ast%")
```

I figure if I can get a regex expression working then I don' t need to use LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM teams WHERE name REGEXP '.*'
```

I'm not very good with sql and even less so with regex. I attempted some regex but haven't figured it out.  Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: You don't need regular expressions - just `REPLACE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) on the column you want to search. This will replace all `.` in the field with nothing, so you can compare it to the word you're searching for.

```
SELECT * FROM teams WHERE replace(name, '.', '') LIKE "%fast%"
```

Comment: I didn't know about replace.  thanks for the help, easier then I thought.